# Help on derivative and relative min/max problem

Tags: calculus

I am not sure where to go on this problem. The question is : Let f be the function defined by $f(x) = k\sqrt{x} - ln(x)$ for $x > 0$, where $k$ is a positive constant.

The first part is to find $f'(x)$ and $f"(x)$. I think  I found $f(x)$ correctly, but I am not sure. I got $$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}(k)(x)^{-1/2} - x^{-1}$$. This is the same as $$\frac{k}{2\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{x}$$. For the second derivative I got $$f''(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{k}{4x^{3/2}}$$.

The problem I am having is in the next part where it says that for a certain value of the constant k, the graph of f has a point of inflection on the x-axis. Find the value of k. I know that inflection points occur when the second derivative changings signs (crosses the x axis), so I set the second derivative to 0. I don't understand how to solve for k, when x is unknown. The previous part asked where it has relative mins/maxes, and I found that it had a relative min at x = 1, k = 2. Should I plug in x = 1 to the second 
derivative and solve for k? This outputs k = 4.

Also, I am wondering how to make the text easier to read, especially the exponents. For me, I see all these ^ ^ ^ signs, and it is pretty difficult to read. Is there a way to format it so it looks more readable? I've seen it around on the site before but I'm not sure how to do that myself. Thank you!

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for help writing math in this site's recommended format. . .

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if there is an inflection point on the x-axis, then the y-coordinate of the point is 0. Therefore, find the x such that f(x)=0, and then plug that back into your f''(x)=0 equation and solve for k.

Answer (score 0):

If we put $f(x)=0$ then $$ k\sqrt{x}= ln(x)$$ for some $$x > 0$$ and if we put $$f''(x)=0$$ at the same time, we should have $$4-k\sqrt{x}=0$$ then $$k\sqrt{x}=4$$ and then $$ln(x)=4$$ and  $$x=e^4$$ Back to $k$ we have $$k=4/\sqrt{x}=4/e^2=4e^{-2}$$